# datatore.put() not adding to db?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a servelet which can take a request from either a rest service or from a jsp form post that will both call a internal method (internalAddPodcast()) to add an entity to the datastore.

When I hit the internalAddPodcast() from the jsp page, it works fine, I can see the that the entity has been added successfully by querying for it right after adding. BUT when I do it from the rest method addPodcast() the datastore.put() doesn't seem to be actually adding to the datastore, because I try and retreive it right after put() and nothing is coming back. Look down near the bottom of this class where I put the comment "//THIS QUERY IS EMPTY WHEN ADDED FROM THE REST SERVICE :(" That is where I expect to have some results come back, especially the entity that I just put in the data store.

```
    package com.aol.sharepodder;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FetchOptions;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQuery;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory;

@Path("/add/podcast/")
public class AddPodcastServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AddPodcastServlet.class
            .getName());

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {

        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        String collectionName = req.getParameter("collectionName");
        String podcast_url = req.getParameter("podcast_url");
        String podcast_description = req.getParameter("podcast_description");
        String podcast_title = req.getParameter("podcast_title");

        log.info("--post adding " + collectionName);

        internalAddPodcast(email, collectionName, podcast_url,
                podcast_description, podcast_title);

        resp.sendRedirect("/collection_details.jsp?collectionName="
                + collectionName + "&email=" + email);
    }

    @POST
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public String addPodcast(
            @DefaultValue("barrand@gmail.com") @FormParam("email") String email,
            @DefaultValue("default") @FormParam("collectionName") String collectionName,
            @DefaultValue("") @FormParam("podcast_url") String podcast_url,
            @DefaultValue("") @FormParam("podcast_description") String podcast_description,
            @DefaultValue("") @FormParam("podcast_title") String podcast_title) {
        try {
            internalAddPodcast(email, collectionName, podcast_url,
                    podcast_description, podcast_title);
            if (podcast_url == "") {
                return "No url supplied";
            }
            return "true";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    private void internalAddPodcast(String email, String collectionName,
            String podcast_url, String podcast_description, String podcast_title) {
        log.info("--INTERNAL ADD ");
        log.info("--email " + email);
        log.info("--collectionName " + collectionName);
        log.info("--podcast_url " + podcast_url);
        log.info("--podcast_description " + podcast_description);
        log.info("--podcast_title " + podcast_title);

        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        User user = userService.getCurrentUser();

        Entity podcast = new Entity("Podcast");
        podcast.setProperty("collectionName", collectionName);
        podcast.setProperty("user", user);
        podcast.setProperty("email", email);
        Date date = new Date();
        podcast.setProperty("date", date);
        podcast.setProperty("podcast_title", podcast_title);
        podcast.setProperty("podcast_description", podcast_description);
        podcast.setProperty("podcast_url", podcast_url);

        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory
                .getDatastoreService();
        datastore.put(podcast);

        //try to log the podcast that I just got done adding to the datastore
        Query query = new Query("Podcast");
        PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(query);

            //THIS QUERY IS EMPTY WHEN ADDED FROM THE REST SERVICE :(
        for (Entity p : pq.asIterable()) {
            log.info("_loop " + " - " + KeyFactory.keyToString(p.getKey())
                    + " -- " + p.getProperty("podcast_title") + " - "
                    + p.getProperty("podcast_url"));
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, and why the entity I'm trying to add from the rest method isn't getting added to the data store.

I know that in both cases, (either from the jsp post, or the rest service) when I get to the internalAddPodcast() all the method params are coming in correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah HA! I found it. I wasn't logging the exception that was being thrown. Basically I was trying to store a string property that was more than 500 characters and it was throwing an exception that I needed to pay attention to :) So it was never getting to the datastore.put()

Comment: This is why you should never, ever, have a `try/catch(Exception e)` around your code.

Answer (score 2):

The High Replication datastore is eventually consistent. That means that most queries are not guaranteed to reflect changes that have just been made to the datastore - including returning records you just inserted. Read more about this and how to do strongly consistent queries [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency).

Comment: thanks for your comment! I found the issue, as noted above. :) I also upped your comment :)